# How to read a "blob" column in mysql

Tags: mysql, blob

How do i read a column of type blob ? The real value behind it is number.
Will just changing the type to int help ? If yes is there another way as well like with a command ?

Comment: `SELECT \`blob_column\` FROM \`mytable\`` ?   there's a big difference between blob and int... which one do you need??  [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

Comment: SELECT `blob_column` FROM `mytable` this will return the normal blob value .. i want to know whats behind the blob

Answer (score 0):

OP's comment:

> SELECT blob_column FROM mytable this will return the normal blob value .. i want to know whats behind the blob

I don't know what that means.  Perhaps you're encoding or serializing the data before inserting it? 
ie, `base64_encode()`, or `json_encode()`

what happens if you:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET `block_column` = 123;
SELECT `blob_column` FROM `mytable`
```

?